# How to output mtr command in human-readable form to standard output?

Tags: osx, routing, traceroute

When I run `sudo mtr 4.2.2.1`, it runs in the Terminal in a loop.

I'd like to keep the same format as below:

```
Host                                                   
1. 192.168.15.1                                        
2. ???
3. 10.254.254.x                                      
4. 10.254.254.x                                     
5. core1.lon2.he.net                           
6. 10gigabitethernet2-1.core1.lon2.he.net
7. a.resolvers.level3.net
```

but printed once to the standard output.

In manual I can see only options to print it in XML, JSON, CSV or RAW formats, but not in the human-readable format as above printed once. Basically I'm interested in similar format when using `traceroute` command, but for `mtr`. Is it possible?

I've tried to run as `sudo mtr -c1 4.2.2.1 | head -n20`, but it breaks the terminal, so I've to `reset` it after each use. Any workaround to that?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to process `mtr`'s output, or keep it displayed after `mtr` quits, you need to run it in report mode, or better, wide report mode:

```
mtr -r -c1 4.2.2.1
```

or

```
mtr -w -c1 4.2.2.1
```

(the difference is that in wide report mode, it won't truncate hostnames).

```
mtr -w -c1 4.2.2.1 | awk 'NR>1 {print $1, $2}'
```

would give something close to what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with `-r`, report mode.

```
sudo mtr -c1 -r 4.2.2.1 | head -n20
```

Or redirected to a file...

```
sudo mtr -c1 -r 4.2.2.1 | head -n20 > out
```

Also, [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com) does not seem to be affected by the screen drawing issue.